# Change default template on adding new template in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Any one help me,

When i add new template in newsletter below mentioned content comes automatically (see also below image). I need to change that template

Step followed:
**Newsletter->Newsletter Templates->Add new template** ( then i see below content in text editor)

where to change the below content in magento

```
Follow this link to unsubscribe

{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
```

[image]

Comment: It is email templates. from their you can edit it.

Comment: I have looked in all email templates. I dont know where it is.
Im look to change.
When i add new template it comes automatically(see that image in question). I need to change that template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i found the file.

It is located in below path. Hope this help anyone in future

**\app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Model\Template.php**

```
public function getTemplateText()
{
    if (!$this->getData('template_text') && !$this->getId()) {
        $this->setData('template_text',
            Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Follow this link to unsubscribe <!-- This tag is for unsubscribe link  --><a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}</a>')
        );
    }

    return $this->getData('template_text');
}
```